# touchesBegan question for iPhone/iPad App

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, xcode4

I have an App and in my touchesBegan, I move an image to another view.  After I move the image I replace the original image with the same image with an alpha of .5.

However, the the user can still touch the 'dimmed' image and move it.  I do not want them to be able to select any of the 'dimmed' images.  I thought maybe I could cancel the touches begin when the user touches the first time, but I am not sure how to cancel it.

UPDATE:
As per the suggestions posted, I have done this in my touchesBegan:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

{
    UITouch * touch = [touches anyObject];
    if (self.alpha >= 1)
    {
        // DO STUFF
    }
    else
        self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
}

However, that does not appear to solve the problem as I can still drag the image and drop it.

Any other ideas would be appreciated!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can disable user interaction on any view using

```
view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not seem to solve the problem. See update above.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I believe this should be done in my touchesEnd, where I set the alpha to dim the image.  I had a spacey moment, I will give that a try.

Comment: you shouldn't put do this in `-touchesBegan:withEvent:`. I suggest you do this soon after dimming the image. I can help further if you can post the code where you dim the image.

Comment: Yes, I put it at the point where I dim the image and it works ok. I had a brain freeze when I read your suggestion earlier.  Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it did not seem to solve the problem. See update above.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake.  I believe this should be done in my touchesEnd, where I set the alpha to dim the image.  I had a spacey moment, I will give that a try.

Comment: r using rect to touch the imageview

Comment: It works now that I moved it to the same place that I dim the image.  Thanks for the suggestions.